# JSF, how to use EL in onclick

Tags: jsf, onclick, el

I want to create links using database columns. I have a backing bean where I 'm connecting to the database. There is no problem with the connection and also no problem with the links names. I can see my links on my browser. I want to use onclick function and that's exactly where the problem starts. How can I use or can I use EL in onclick?

A little example:

```
<h:dataTable rows="7" value="#{frontSiteMenu.links}" var="row"
    styleClass="sitemenu" width="200">
    <h:column>
        <a href="#" onclick="dispNewsGroup('${row.newsGroupId}')"><h:outputText value='#{row.newsGroup}' /></a>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I take it you are using JSPs?

Use [h:outputLink](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/1.2_MR1/docs/tlddocs/h/outputLink.html) instead of an *a* tag and change the expression use the # character:

```
<h:outputLink value="#" onclick="dispNewsGroup('#{row.newsGroupId}')">
    <h:outputText value='#{row.newsGroup}' />
</h:outputLink>
```

That is untested, but should be close to what you want.

The spec says this about # vs $:

> ...by convention the J2EE
>   web tier specifications use the
>   ${expr} construct for immediate
>   evaluation and the #{expr} construct
>   for deferred evaluation.

So, in a repeat control where the underlying values change, it is desirable to use deferred evaluation.

There are also issues with using non-JSF tags as children of some JSF controls, so it is best to stick to using JSF controls where possible (though there is a [f:verbatim](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/1.2_MR1/docs/tlddocs/f/verbatim.html) tag). Many of these issues go away if you move to the newer Facelets view technology.